# How to select rows with similar entries in a column? MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table like;

**tablea**

[image: tablea]

```
4c4fedf7    OMoy3Hoa
4c4fedf7    yiWDGB4D
broe4AMb    A9rLRawV
broe4AMb    mi9rLmZW
nhrtK9ce    yEsBoYLj
rEEtK9gt    A9rLRawV
rEEtK9gt    mi9rLmZW
rEEtK9Hh    A9rLRawV
rEEtK9Hh    msBWz8CQ
```

I have an input like `A9rLRawV`,`mi9rLmZW`. I want an output like;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```

But I get output like;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
rEEtK9Hh
```

My query is like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT prodid
FROM tablea
WHERE tagid IN ('A9rLRawV','mi9rLmZW');
```

Here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12223/2/0

I think it needs a self join. What will be the most 'efficient' method? How can I fix this?

Comment: from your query, you will really get 3 output. rEEtK9Hh will return because it satisfies the WHERE condition tagid = 'A9rLRawV', (edit: OK, I got what you want now.)

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.prodid from(
SELECT  prodid
FROM tablea
group by prodid, tagid
having tagid IN ('A9rLRawV') or tagid in('mi9rLmZW')) a
group by prodid
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score -2):

If I get what you want with your data, please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prodid
FROM tablea
WHERE tagid = 'mi9rLmZW' AND tagid = 'A9rLRawV';
```

As per my understanding with your situation, you want to get all prodid with both tagid of mi9rLmZW and A9rLRawV. By using WHERE tagid IN... you are also selecting rEEtK9Hh. You need to use AND to just get prodid with tagid both mi9rLmZW and A9rLRawV.